# Error installing pygame on MacOS: 'longintrepr.h' file not found

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I am trying to install the pygame library on my Mac running macOS 11.0 Big Sur, but I keep getting errors related to missing files, such as 'longintrepr.h' and 'pkg-config'. I have tried installing the library using pip3 and a virtual environment, but I am still encountering the same issues. I am looking for a solution to successfully install the pygame library on my Mac.

```
 #include "longintrepr.h"
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      
      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---
      
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pygame

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I have the newest version of python3 installed.

I tried to install pygame using pip on my MacOS machine but I encountered an error "src_c/_sdl2/sdl2.c:211:12: fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found" during the installation process. I also tried creating a virtual environment and installing pygame there but still encountered the same error. I was expecting the installation process to complete successfully without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the official [pygame repo](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/3522), there's a huge thread regarding installation of pygame in python 3.11 (latest version) not working properly yet.

Try installing `pip install pygame --pre` for now, which is going to install a developmental release of the newest, prereleased pygame version, or if you want stability using an older version of python also works.